# VSCode/Vue3 - How to enable object property viewer on hover and vue snippet issue

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Hello guys I'm new on Vue3, recently I saw tutorial that when he is hovering the object show the structure of the object inside like image below.
[image]

1. How to enable it like image above on .vue file?
2. Also sometimes my vue snippet and javascript ES6 snippet didn't work on .vue file? I already installed these extension on my VSCode, is there anything I need to setup to make it work?
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't from `vue`. The only way you can get that is by using `Typescript` which I think you are not using on your project at least not in your `vue` files. You need to install Typescript on your project in order to have that.

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

[How to Integrate Typescript with Vue.Js](https://blog.theodo.com/2019/11/integrate-typescript-with-vue/)

[Using vue with typescript](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview)

You also need to add the lang used in you , to tell vscode to read your script part as `Typescript` and not `Javascript`:

Composition API :

```
<script setup> -> <script setup lang="ts">
```

Options API:

```
<script> -> <script lang="ts">
```

For the second problem, it probably comes from a config issue in your vscode, and it's hard to help you on that without further information.